# Fancybox not displaying iframe contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fancybox-2

I'm having trouble using fancybox to display iframe content in my application. I'm able to get it work in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RHaAX/634/ but not within my application. I've also tried changing the link in the fiddle example to the page I'm trying to display in my application, in case it was something specific about my application, and it still works fine.

Here are the include I do at the beginning of the .php page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
<!-- Add mousewheel plugin (this is optional) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>
<!-- Add fancyBox main JS and CSS files -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.3"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scripts/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.3" media="screen" />
<!-- Add fancyBox - button helper (this is optional) -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scripts/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=2.1.3" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=2.1.3"></script>
<!-- Add fancyBox - thumbnail helper (this is optional) -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scripts/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=2.1.3" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=2.1.3"></script>
<!-- Add fancyBox - media helper (this is optional) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.0"></script>
```

I've checked the javascript console and indeed the .js and .css files are all found. Here is the javascript and html I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.fancybox').fancybox({type: "iframe", iframe: {preload: false}});
}
</script>
<a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-type="iframe" title="SGE status" href="pipelines.php?action=viewjob&id=<?=$analysis_qsubid?>">processing</a>
```

Any idea what might be causing this not to work?

Answer (score 0):

Seem like you're missing closing `)` in your code:

```
$(function() {
    $('.fancybox').fancybox({type: "iframe", iframe: {preload: false}});
}); // <-- Here
```

Comment: Looks like I missed a ); when copying the code to here, but it is correct in my application